# Await for a page to return a value

Tags: uwp, windows-10

I am making photo editing app, and I have a `ImageEditor.xaml.cs`. How do I make this page behave like `FileOpenPicker` which can return value(s) to a collection after the `FileOpenPicker`is done picking the desired files? Or this is impossible? If so, how do I make the `Mainpage.xaml.cs` navigate to and await until `ImageEditor.xaml.cs` return the edited photo so that `Mainpage` can receive the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If so, how do I make the Mainpage.xaml.cs navigate to and await until ImageEditor.xaml.cs return the edited photo so that Mainpage can receive the value?

Since you didn't mention that you've used any template for development, so I assume that you use the standard UWP Apis.

Then, a quite easy way to do this is that after getting the edited image, directly navigate to your `MainPage` with this image as navi-parameter using [Frame.Navigate(TypeName, Object) method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh702394.aspx). Then you can override the `OnNavigatedTo` of your `MainPage` just like this:

```cs
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    //get e.Parameter
}
```

For official demo, you can refer to [Pass information between pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/navigate-between-two-pages#pass-information-between-pages).

If you used template like `Template 10` for development of UWP app, then usually they have their own `NavigationService` and navigation method, but usually a navi-parameter can be used in those methods.

> How do I make this page behave like FileOpenPicker which can return value(s) to a collection after the FileOpenPickeris done picking the desired files?

As an additional information for this case, the point here is get the result of another instance in the same process before navigation, it's not quite like `FileOpenPicker`, `FileOpenPicker` actually uses a system broker to break the sandbox of UWP app, it is getting result from a different process. Anyway, using Navigation with parameter can already solve your issue I think.